# A requisição PUT não está enviando o objeto todo

Tags: javascript, json

Esse é o put que eu estou dando, (mais abaixo vai ter o *JSON* que está vindo do body):

```
put(endpoint: string, body: any) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return this.http.put(this.url + '/' + endpoint, body)
      .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res.json())
        },
        (error: any) => {
          this.loader.hide();
          this.MessageErroRequest(error);
        });
  });
}
```

O método está enviando assim:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "nome": "LESPAUL",
  "validade": 1525568400000,
  "dataGerada": 1525914000000,
  "status": true,
  "itens": [
    []
  ]
}
```

E o objeto que eu estou mandando é assim, simplesmente ele não vai, quando eu coloco o BODY ele retira o Array "itens":

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "nome": "LESPAUL",
  "validade": 1525568400000,
  "dataGerada": 1525914000000,
  "status": true,
  "itens": [{
    "cliente": {
      "id": 1,
      "login": "gabriel",
      "senha": "123",
      "tipoDeLogin": 1,
      "telefone": "99916-2410",
      "endereco": "Zetete Tororo 25",
      "nome": "Gabriel Sereno",
      "cpf": "12312312312"
    }
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Que linguagem é essa? Marque a tag da linguagem

Comment: Mas onde não chega isso? No `NodeJS`? Em qual tipo de servidor?